# Cannot auto (or Force) dismiss keypad on iPad (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

My app have a list of Contact(it loads from native contact into my iPad) and a list of Buddy chat. When I add my buddy to my contact, and then click on search bar to search contact -> the keypad is show. The problem is when I click on search button of keypad(or cancel on search bar) and then the keypad is not dismissing even though the below function is called:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sBar
{
 [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and even I call `[self.view endEditing:YES];` it's also not work. And when I touch some another button into my app to show **popover** the keypad is also not dismiss-> it's means the follow code is not work `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];`. **If I am not try to add my buddy to my contact**, the keypad is auto dismiss when I click button to show **popover** Or when I click on search button the keypad will dismiss smoothly.

How to force the keypad dismiss?

Comment: Can your try: [self.view endEditing:YES]; ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //try this
 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sBar
 {
      [sBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: I also called this function. But it not work when I try add my buddy to my contact list. If I am not do that, this function is work.

Comment: Did you give delegate to UISearchBar?

Comment: sBar or searchBar(my outlet) is the same, don't need to replace it.

Comment: Yes, I had do that. as I said, everything work ok if I'm not try to add my buddy to my contact list. I think this action is problem but I don't know why???

Answer (score 0):

Take three Step in count

1) set delegate for textfield

2) set Delegate for particular textfielf yourtextfielg.delegate=self.

3) Resign that particular textField [txt resignFirstResponder].

Comment: I had do that before.I think the problem is the action when I add my buddy to my contacts list. But why when I do that, it's had affect on auto dismiss keypad action?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

**You need the UI field to resign the first responder status to dismiss the keyboard.**

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; //It might not work
```

**or**

```
[field resignFirstResponder]; //it will surely work
}
```

Comment: when I placed break point into my code line, I can see that the command [searchBar resignFirstResponder];(or [self.view endEditing YES]; if I replaced) is also called. But it's not affect. it's mean don't need to add a gesture as your advice. The problem need to solve is why the command also called, but it's not work.